# Google Drive API and Google Apps Script

Tags: android, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I've made an Android app which uses the Google Drive API to list the files in a user's Drive and open the files. Whilst most files open as expected, there is an issue when trying to open Google Apps Script project files: the file.getDownloadUrl() returns null, so I am unable to retrieve it from Drive.

Whilst I can understand why the Google Drive API does not return a download URL for the projects, what I was wondering is if there was any way of opening the files in the project via the Drive API (or any other Android-compatible API). The app is a code editor, so this would be an extremely useful feature to have! Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Apps Script projects can't be downloaded but exported.

Basically you can use the export link of the Drive.File and get a JSON object containing all the files of the Google Apps Script Project.

More details are available in the [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/import-export).

Comment: Great! As long as the modified project can then be imported back into the original then that should work brilliantly

Comment: Yes, the Import export was made just to do that, on the release date a plugin for eclipse [1] was released and Google Drive integrated editors now support edit of Google Apps Script projects leveraging this feature to read and write back the script after edit [2]  [1] https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/apps_script  [2] http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ePD7sJEeRkI